# How to receive a watchOS file transfer on iOS in the background

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using transferFile and I can successfully send and receive files, but in order to complete the transfer process, I need to open up the iPhone app.

In observing other apps, it appears that they are able to receive and act upon received data in the background (and send a push notification to the user, for example).

I am wondering how they did this.

Comment: watchapp can send instant message that will wake up ios app, so your file will be delivered while iosapp is still background active: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, I am noticing that the message will not be received once the WCSession on the phone is no longer active. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You should send a message from the watch app to the phone using the sendMessage function of watch connectivity requesting the data. This will wake up the iphone app. Then in your didreceivemessage method on the phone you should use the filetransfer function to send your files to the watch.

To clarify when a message is sent using sendMessage this wakes the iphone application up in the background to receive the message to where it can respond with a file transfer. Hope this helps

You need to send a message first before sending the file transfer. Implement something like this on your watch side

```
func sendActivationMessage() {
    if session.activationState == .activated && session.isReachable {
        session.sendMessage(["Watch Message" : "Activate"], replyHandler: { 
    (reply) in

            if reply["Phone Message"] as! String == "Activated" {
                //This is where you should implement your file transfer
            }
        }, errorHandler: { (error) in

            print("***** Error Did Occur: \(error) *****")
        })
    } else {
        print("***** Activation Error *****")
    }
}
```

Then in your didreceivemessage function on the phone side implement something like this

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

    if let messageFromWatch = message["Watch Message"] {
        let messageData = messageFromWatch as! String

        //Message From Watch to Activate Watch Connectivity Session
        if messageData == "Activate" {
            replyHandler(["Phone Message" : "Activated"])
        }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this, but file transfers still do not complete if the watch has been away from the phone long enough for the phone's WCSession to deactivate. Then, it is required for the phone app to be opened to finish the transfer. I wish there was a way around this, but it looks like other apps suffer the same limitation.

Comment: you need to send a message first. I added a code example to my answer

Comment: sendMessage will wake the phone in the background. transferFile will not.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. If the session is deactivated (for example, if the user has been far away from their phone for more than 10 minutes or so, or if bluetooth has been re-enabled without re-opening the app), then send message does not wake up the iPhone app, and I still need to open the app for the message to be received. To expand, the isReachable variable will be false in this case.